# Retrieving all data while COUNTING the rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to retrieve all of the data in the table concern, and count all of the rows that It will return.

My query works fine when I didn't use `count()`, it gives me all the rows.

The problem is when I added the `count(con_id)` it only returns a single row.

***How do I retrieve all the data, at the same time, count the rows that it returned?***

**table user_info**

```
user_id     fname      lname
1           Ano        Nymous
2           blank      blank
```

**table concern**

```
con_id   user_id     con_subject     con_message     con_date      con_reply
1        1           server lag      pls fix it      2015-08-30    
2        1           help            pls fix it      2015-09-01    
3        2           blah blah       pls fix it      2015-09-02  
4        2           test            pls fix it      2015-09-03  
5        1           testt           pls fix it      2015-09-04
```

**this is my query:**

```
SELECT fname,lname,con_id,user_id,con_subject,
con_message,con_date,con_reply, COUNT(con_id) AS 'returned_rows'
FROM concern
JOIN user_info
ON concern.user_id = user_info.user_id
ORDER BY con_date
```

The **output of this is**

```
fname   lname   con_id  con_subject    con_message   con_date    con_reply  returned_rows 
Ano     Nymous  1       serverlag      pls fix it    2015-08-30             5
```

**This is my desired output**

```
fname   lname   con_id  con_subject    con_message   con_date    con_reply  returned_rows 
Ano     Nymous  1       server lag     pls fix it    2015-08-30             5
Ano     Nymous  2       help           pls fix it    2015-09-01
blank   blank   3       blah blah      pls fix it    2015-09-02
blank   blank   4       test           pls fix it    2015-09-03
Ano     Nymous  5       testt          pls fix it    2015-09-04
```

Comment: count is an aggregate function you need a group by clause in order to get correct results

Comment: SELECT fname,lname,con_id,user_id,con_subject,
con_message,con_date,con_reply, (select COUNT(con_id) 
FROM concern
JOIN user_info
ON concern.user_id = user_info.user_id) AS 'returned_rows'
FROM concern
JOIN user_info
ON concern.user_id = user_info.user_id
ORDER BY con_date

Comment: Use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery:

SELECT fname,lname,con_id,user_id,con_subject, con_message,con_date,con_reply,
 (select COUNT(con_id) FROM concern JOIN user_info ON concern.user_id = user_info.user_id) AS 'returned_rows' FROM concern JOIN user_info ON concern.user_id = user_info.user_id ORDER BY con_date

Comment: Having provided this answer I would have to note that it is not very efficient and you would be better off getting the count after retrieving the data in most cases...

Comment: Ohh. I thought it will be more efficient when I use this, instead of 2 queries. I'm using this for my PHP code btw. thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  However, if you want the column in the query itself, you can use a subquery and variables:

```
SELECT t.*, @rn as returned_rows
FROM (SELECT fname, lname, con_id, user_id, con_subject, con_message,
             con_date, con_reply, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM concern JOIN
           user_info
           ON concern.user_id = user_info.user_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      ORDER BY con_date
     ) t;
```

The variable value is calculated in the subquery.  It is then used in the outer query.

Comment: It works fine like subquery, but what does it mean by @ rn := @ rn +1 ?

Comment: @KennethC . . . That is setting a value for the variable.  In fact, you can also use this same construct to enumerate the rows of the output.  The query will put them in a column called `rn`.